# Отправка HTML+CSS письма в Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Во `view` содержится шаблон письма с HTML и отдельным блоком `<style>`.

Но почему-то на почту приходит голое письмо без CSS. В настройках рассылки указано: `$config['mailtype']  = 'html';`

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk подозреваю, что там можно работать только инлайн-стилями

Comment: Там - это во фреймворке? Или в стандарте отсылки писем?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk в письмах

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, почитайте про верстку html-писем. Там куча правил. Одно из них - это использование только inline styles.